# Query in apex attribute of a component

Tags: soql, visualforce-component

Is it safe to put soql query as a string in apex attribute of a component? Or is it a stupid idea?

For example

```
<apex:component controller="somecontroller"><apex:attribute name = "query" type="String" required="true" description=""/>
</apex:component>
```

and then use it as below for example:

```
<c:myCmp query="SELECT Id from Account"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding using this if other means are possible, but it's fine as long as you remember to enforce security on the server so that this can't be abused.

```
return Database.query(queryString, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
```

This will ensure that the component can't return records it shouldn't have access to.

Never allow a system-level query to be accessible to direct user input.